# How to calculate volume of NTFS disk

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

In Linux, I create a 2G size file as virtual disk and format to NTFS, but its size is not 2G, exactly there is a short of 17170432 Bytes, and that value turns to be 13402112 Bytes for a 3G file.

I just know that there is 512 Bytes for MBR table, but what about the else? How can i know the exact volume of a virtual disk which is format from a file?

Answer (score 0):

'I just know that there is 512 Bytes for MBR table, but what about the else?' - a whole pile of NTFS microsoft-proprietary journalling file system metadata.

'How can i know the exact volume of a virtual disk which is format from a file?'  No idea - nobody I know of has ever tried - "I guessed about 2 gig, so I formatted five".  Storage is so cheap that sizing file systems is not worth spending any time on.